# How to add "key" inside foreach loop with array in php

Tags: php, arrays

I am working with php, Right now i am getting array in this format using foreach loop

```
Array
     (
       [id] => 1
       [uname] => Lorem Ipsum dummy text 1
     )
Array
     (
        [id] => 2
        [uname] => Lorem Ipsum dummy text 2
     )
```

But i want to add key(dynamic) above every array,my expected array format is  (i have dynamic key(3,7)),How can i do this ?

```
Array
   (
     [3] => Array
       (
         [id] => 1
         [uname] => Lorem Ipsum dummy text 1
       ),
     [7] => Array
        (
          [id] => 2
          [uname] => Lorem Ipsum dummy text 2 
        )
      )
```

Here is my current code

```
foreach($reportProduct as $data) {
        echo '<pre>'; print_r($data);
      }
```

Comment: From where did you get that 3 and 7? Do you know associative arrays?

Comment: where did 3 and 7 came from

Comment: Could you explain what you need this for? If we know that, it's easier for us to come up with good suggestions and see if it's a [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/) or not.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your 3 or 7 coming from somewhere .
Here's how y

```php
<?php


$d=[
    [
        "id"=>1,
        "name"=>"Ketan",
    ],
    [
        "id"=>2,
        "name"=>"Shiv",
    ]
    ];

$formatted_arr = [];

//replace this with source of keys
$dynamic_keys=[3,7];

foreach ($d as $key => $data) {
   $formatted_arr[$dynamic_keys[$key]]=$data;
}
print_r($formatted_arr);
```